# How to find refraction vector from incoming vector and surface normal?

Tags: java, vector, raytracing

I'm writing a ray tracer in java and I'm trying to implement refraction, but I'm getting confused by the information I'm finding on the subject. If I have a 3D vector for the incoming ray of light, the surface normal given as a 3D Vector and the refractive indexes of the two mediums what operations do I need to apply in order to get the vector of the transmitted ray?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law#Vector_form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let **V_incedence** be the normalized incoming vector. Let `n1` and `n2` be the refracting indices of the two surfaces. You want to calculate **V_refraction**. Let **n** be the normalized normal vector.

```
V_refraction = r*V_incedence + (rc - sqrt(1-Math.pow(r,2)(1-Math.pow(c,2))))n
where r = n1/n2 and c = -n dot V_incedence.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the first line does that mean adding the vector of V_incedence.multiply(r) with the vector of n.multiply(rc - sqrt(1-r^2(1-c^2)))?

Comment: Is this an approximation? Seems to be off by some decimal places

Answer (score 7):

Bram de Greve wrote a nice article about reflections and refractions in ray tracing. You can find it [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs148-10-summer/docs/2006--degreve--reflection_refraction.pdf).

His implementation (C++) looks like this:

```
Vector refract(const Vector& normal, const Vector& incident, 
               double n1, double n2) 
{
    const double n = n1 / n2;
    const double cosI = -dot(normal, incident);
    const double sinT2 = n * n * (1.0 - cosI * cosI);
    if(sinT2 > 1.0) return Vector::invalid; // TIR
    const double cosT = sqrt(1.0 - sinT2);
    return n * incident + (n * cosI - cosT) * normal;
}
```

Here is the PBRTv3 implementation (under BSD-2-Clause license):

```
inline bool Refract(const Vector3f &wi, const Normal3f &n, Float eta,
                    Vector3f *wt) {
    // Compute $\cos \theta_\roman{t}$ using Snell's law
    Float cosThetaI = Dot(n, wi);
    Float sin2ThetaI = std::max(Float(0), Float(1 - cosThetaI * cosThetaI));
    Float sin2ThetaT = eta * eta * sin2ThetaI;

    // Handle total internal reflection for transmission
    if (sin2ThetaT >= 1) return false;
    Float cosThetaT = std::sqrt(1 - sin2ThetaT);
    *wt = eta * -wi + (eta * cosThetaI - cosThetaT) * Vector3f(n);
    return true;
}
```

See my [blog](https://vertexwahn.de/2020/12/19/refraction/) how to implement it test driven.

Comment: This was a quite helpful awnser even though I had to write cosI = abs(dot(normal, incident)) in order for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this in my ray java tracer take a look https://github.com/bradforj287/brads-java-raytracer

```
private static double clamp(final double val, final double min, final double max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, val));
}

private Vector3d getRefractionVector(final Vector3d I, final Vector3d N, final double ior) {
    double cosi = clamp(-1, 1, I.dot(N));
    double etai = 1, etat = ior;
    Vector3d n = N;
    if (cosi < 0) {
        cosi = -cosi;
    } else {
        double temp = etai;
        etai = etat;
        etat = temp;
        n = N.multiply(-1);
    }
    double eta = etai / etat;
    double k = 1 - (eta * eta) * (1 - (cosi * cosi));
    if (k <= 0) {
        return Vector3d.ZERO;
    } else {
        return I.multiply(eta).add(n.multiply(((eta * cosi) - Math.sqrt(k))));
    }
}
```